# Is a vector a multiple of some other vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\bf a_1,\ldots, a_m$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n \geq 2$. Does there exist 
$$
B=\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
                            0 & b_1 & \cdots & b_{n-1} \end{array}\right]
$$
such that $B {\bf a_1}=\left[\begin{array}{c} a_{11} \\ 
                            \sum_{j=2}^n b_ja_{1j} \end{array}\right]$ is not a multiple of $B {\bf a_i}=\left[\begin{array}{c} a_{i1} \\ 
                            \sum_{j=2}^n b_ja_{ij} \end{array}\right]$ for all $i=2,\ldots, m$?

I think the answer is that such a $B$ exists if and only if $\bf a_1$ is not a multiple of $\bf a_i$ for all $i=2,\ldots, m$. I'm sure of sufficiency (the proof seems obvious but can't quite put arguments together) but not sure of necessity.

P.S. Not sure if the "Title" of this question is a good one.

Edit: The question is answered in @Omnomnomnom notation replicated here.

We have a matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{a_{11} & \cdots &a_{1n}\\ \mathbf{v}_1 & \cdots & \mathbf v_{n}}
$$
with $\mathbf v_i \in \Bbb R^{n-1}$, and we would like to select
$$
B = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0& \mathbf b ^T}
$$
where $\mathbf b \in \Bbb R^{n-1}$ such that the first column of $BA$ is not a multiple of any other.

---

In fact, if we can suppose $a_{1i} \neq 0$, it is equivalent to ask the same question about the product $B\tilde A$, where we define
$$
\tilde A = \pmatrix{1 & \cdots & 1\\ \frac{1}{a_{11}}\mathbf{v}_1 & \cdots & \frac{1}{a_{1n}}\mathbf v_{n}} := 
\pmatrix{1 & \cdots & 1\\ \tilde v_1 & \cdots & \tilde v_n}
$$
In this case, two columns will only be multiples if they are also equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in the case of $a_{1i} \neq 0$ for all $i$:

Suppose that $a_1$ is a multiple of $a_i$ for some $a_i$.  This means that $\tilde v_1 = \tilde v_i$.  It follows that $b^T \tilde v_1 = b^T \tilde v_i$ for any choice of $b$.

Now, suppose that no suitable $B$ exists. That is, suppose that our $\tilde v_i$ are such that for any $b$, there is a choice of $i > 1$ such that $b^T \tilde v_1 = b^T \tilde v_i$. That is, suppose that there is a set $S = \{\tilde v_{i_1},\dots,\tilde v_{i_k}\}$ such that $b^T \tilde v_1 = b^T \tilde v_{i_k}$ for some choice of $k$, where the choice of $k$ may depend on $b$.

For any $v \in S$, we define K_v the set of vectors $b$ such that $b^T v = b^T \tilde v_1$.  That is, $K_v$ is the set of vectors $b$ such that $b^T(v - \tilde v_1) = 0$.  That is, K_v is the kernel of the linear transformation $T(x)$ defined by
$$
T(x) = x^T(v - \tilde v_1)
$$
which, in particular, means that each $K_v$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{n-1}$.

Now, define $K = \cup_{v \in S} K_v$.  The above statement is equivalent to the statement $K = \Bbb R^{n-1}$.  However, the union of finitely many proper subspaces of $\Bbb R^{n-1}$ cannot be equal to $\Bbb R^{n-1}$ (remember: the union of two subspaces is only a subspace if one contains the other).  Thus, there exists a $v \in S$ such that $K_v = \Bbb R^{n-1}$.

That is, there is an $i>1$ such that $b^T v_1 = b^T v_i$ for every $b \in \Bbb R^{n-1}$.  By considering $b = (1,0,\dots,0)^T, b = (0,1,0,\dots,0)^T,$ and so forth, we conclude that $v_1 = v_i$.

Thus, $a_1$ must be a multiple of some $a_i$ for $i>1$, as desired.

---

As for the other cases: note that, assuming $b \neq 0$ and $a_1 \neq 0$, $B a_1$ can only be a multiple of $B a_i$ if the first entries of $a_1$ and $a_i$ are both either zero or non-zero.  Using this fact, we may conclude that the necessity and sufficiency of your condition holds in general.

Comment: There's a lot of machinery involved in this proof, but it all comes down to linear algebra basics.  Let me know if anything needs clarifying.

Comment: Looks correct.... maybe a way to streamline proof is with lemma like: for any set of nonzero vectors $\bf v_1,\ldots,\bf v_m$ there exists a vector $\bf b$ such that $\bf b^T \bf v_i \neq 0$. Sketch of proof by induction: when $m=1$ let $\bf b= \bf v_1$. Now suppose $\bf \widetilde b^T \bf v_i \neq 0$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$ and consider $\bf \widetilde b + c v_{m+1}$ for some nonzero constant $c$. Then if $\bf \widetilde b^T v_i=0$ when $c=c_i$ just choose a $c$ different from $c_i$...

Comment: Do you mean a vector such that $b^T v_i \neq 0$ for all $i$? I could believe that, but how would it help?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant ... If I understand your proof correctly the second part assumes no $B$ exists and shows $v_1=v_i$. Instead, we can use the lemma to show that if $v_1$ is not a multiple of any $v_i$ then such a $B$ exists... I'll add another answer to clarify what I mean.

Comment: @user103828 to be sure, that lemma (which is true as long as all $v_i \neq 0$) is essentially identical to the fact I proved, which is that $\bigcup K_v$ can only be the entire space if one of the $v$ are equal to $0$.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the same... I thought it would just be cleaner to state it in a lemma that is all I meant by the comment.

Comment: Oh, fair enough.  Yes, I suppose I could organize this proof a bit to make it more readable.  However, I don't think any of the essential steps can be left out.  Would it help if I rewrote this to explicitly prove your lemma and use that?

Comment: No, it's not necessary but thanks for offering... Just to check, I had in mind something like this for the second part of the proof ``Suppose now that $a_1$ is not a multiple of $a_i$ for all $a_i$ i.e. $\widetilde v_1 \neq \widetilde v_i$ for all $i$. Then we need to show that there exists a $b$ such that $b^T (\widetilde v_1-\widetilde v_i) \neq 0$ for all $i$. This follows from the lemma.''

Comment: @user103828 that absolutely works.  I can see I was actually a bit redundant in worrying about the set $S$.  I do suggest you prove the lemma with a dimension argument similar to mine rather than the constructive argument you're heading towards.